# Select query except another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got 2 tables.

**TABLE 1**

```
ID  FRANCHISENAME    TELEPHONE   FRANCHISE_ID
1    BURGER          666-555-999     5
2    JSUBS           666-555-999     7
3    STEAKS          777-888-999     3
```

**TABLE 2**

```
ID  NAME     TELEPHONE    EMAIL           FRANCHISE_ ID
5   JOHN     555-444-333  JOHN@GMAIL.COM       5
5   JOHN     555-444-333  JOHN@GMAIL.COM       7
6   EDGARD   555-444-333  EDGARD@GMAIL.COM     9
```

I want to retrieve all data in table one, except for that data where the user has his email in Table 2. As for example `JOHN` has `franchise_id` `5` and `7`, so the query would only return

```
3 STEAKS, 777-888-999, 3
```

Comment: How do these two tables relate to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming that `TABLE_1` & `TABLE_2` relate to each other through `TABLE_1.FRANCHISE_ID` & `TABLE_2.FRANCHISE_ID`*

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT
*
FROM TABLE_1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT *
   FROM TABLE_2 T2 
   WHERE T2.FRANCHISE_ID = T1.FRANCHISE_ID
   AND T2.EMAIL = 'JOHN@GMAIL.COM'
)
```

**OR**

You can use `LEFT JOIN` along with `IS NULL`

```
SELECT
T1.*
FROM TABLE_1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.FRANCHISE_ID = T2.FRANCHISE_ID
WHERE T2.FRANCHISE_ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: The query needs to have somewhere table2.email = "JOHN@GMAIL.COM", so it knows it has to return everything except that.

Comment: I've updated the query using `NOT EXISTS`. Please check and inform. @GerardoBastidas

Comment: Just Perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
    Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.FRANCHISE_ID = t2.FRANCHISE_ID
    AND LEN(IFNULL(t2.EMAIL,'')) > 0
WHERE
    t2.ID IS NULL
```

Even if there is a record in Table 2 if it has no email it will be returned by this query.  You can expand say to > 7 or more to check for a minimum level of validity of email address.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there using the NOT IN function. It will exclude records from Table 1 if there is a matching Franchise ID in Table 2, unless the email field is Table 2 is null:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Franchise_ID NOT IN
(SELECT Table2.Franchise_ID FROM Table2
WHERE Table2.Email IS NOT NULL);
```